# Do I get some reward when a site I proposed goes beta?

Tags: discussion, area-51

My proposal just hit beta, and people started pouring in. I expected some badge on area51, but I got nothing. A bit anticlimatic, or maybe something will happen later on ?

Comment: The satisfaction of knowing that you were the genesis of a potentially successful community isn't enough?

Comment: You get a site where you can ask questions on a subject you are intered in.

Comment: @casperOne : the same can be said for every operation I do on SO/SE. The mechanism of badges is to mark milestones and achievements.

Answer (score 12):

There is no badge<sup>1</sup> for getting a site into beta, but there is [one you should get](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges?filter=gold) for *completing* beta:

> - **Founder:** Participated in the definition, commitment, and beta phases of a successful site

Badges aren't awarded automatically: assuming you meet the requirements, you should receive it within 24 hours.

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>: There's is, however, the *Revolution* badge (and its silver/bronze equivalents), which was to have a proposal with 100 followers or committers. Since you need 200 committers to get into beta, you should've gotten it long ago.

Comment: @StefanoBorini I misread the Founder badge; there is indeed no badge for getting a site into beta: have to make it to launch.

Comment: ;_; ;_; ;_; ;_;

Answer (score 2):

A bucket load of reputation that won't go away should be a good enough reward;-) Not to mention the inevitable badges that will result

Aside from that, there are a few opportunities for rewards, but the second person to join the project gets just as much as the original person, including the Founder badge, among others.